# compiling bash doesn't work, LFS

Tags: linux, bash, make, manjaro, lfs

I have been following the instructions of the LFS manual so far but have come to an error when making bash, I ran `make` in the bash-5.1 folder but it displayed an error at the end of the command output:

```
/mnt/lfs/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ./lib/sh/libsh.a(tmpfile.o): in function `sh_mktmpname':
/mnt/lfs/sources/bash-5.1/lib/sh/tmpfile.c:160: warning: the use of `mktemp' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp' or `mkdtemp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:583: bash] Error 1
```

All the commands I ran before this one have worked, I also ran `echo $?` and it outputted 2. I am on the latest version of manjaro.

Comment: What you've posted here is a *warning*... your `ld` *error* is something else that happened somewhere previously. It's always helpful to post the LFS Book version (10.1?) and the chapter/section you're currently on (6.4?). Additionally, please re-read [help](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter01/askforhelp.html), specifically the section "Compilation Problems" which explains why the output you've posted here isn't enough to help you solve your problem.

Comment: ...also, something that often helps when tracking down an error is to (re)build with a single job: `make -j1`. This causes the build to exit quicker when there is an error, instead of waiting for multiple parallel, pending jobs to complete... the result is that the *real* error is closer to the bottom of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I incorrectly compiled ncurses, deleting the ncurses directory and then starting from their did the trick.